# Selecting groups in which one or more rows meet certain criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I am cleaning up data in R using the `tidyverse` package. I would like to select all groups in which one or more rows meet a certain criterion.

I have a data that looks like the following:

```
require(tidyverse)
dat <- data_frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"),3),
  key = c(1,1,0, 0,0,0,1,0,0),
  value = rnorm(n= 9, mean = 3, sd = 1)
)

#A tibble: 9 x 3
#Groups:   group [3]
  group   key value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1  3.97
2 B         1  2.05
3 C         0  3.28
4 A         0  4.22
5 B         0  2.67
6 C         0  5.02
7 A         1  2.60
8 B         0  3.99
9 C         0  4.42
```

For this example, I would like to select groups in which one or more keys equal to 1. Only group A and B include rows whose key is 1. Hence, my expected results would be:

```
#A tibble: 9 x 3
#Groups:   group [3]
  group   key value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1  3.97
2 B         1  2.05
4 A         0  4.22
5 B         0  2.67
7 A         1  2.60
8 B         0  3.99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relatively simple solutions is as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(12345)

dat <- data_frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"),3),
  key = c(1,1,0, 0,0,0,1,0,0),
  value = rnorm(n= 9, mean = 3, sd = 1)
)

dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(sum(key == 1) > 0)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>   group   key value
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A         1  3.59
#> 2 B         1  3.71
#> 3 A         0  2.55
#> 4 B         0  3.61
#> 5 A         1  3.63
#> 6 B         0  2.72
```

Once you have grouped by a variable, you can apply a filter, remembering that any functions calling a variable will be applied to the vector of that variable belonging only to the group.

Comment: Thank you so much, @g_t_m!! Super quick and that's exactly what I was looking for. I'vs never thought of using sum there. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `ave` would be

```
dat[with(dat, ave(key == 1, group, FUN = function(x) any(sum(x) > 0))), ]

# group   key value
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A        1. 0.875
#2 B        1. 2.61 
#3 A        0. 3.30 
#4 B        0. 1.40 
#5 A        1. 4.52 
#6 B        0. 3.34
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options.

**1)** using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[dat[, .I[sum(key == 1) > 0], group]$V1]
#    group key value
#1:     A   1  3.97
#2:     A   0  4.22
#3:     A   1  2.60
#4:     B   1  2.05
#5:     B   0  2.67
#6:     B   0  3.99
```

---

**2)** with `base R`

**a)** in a compact way with `ave`

```
dat[!!with(dat, ave(key, group, FUN = max)), ]
```

**b)**  using `table`

```
subset(dat, group %in% names(which(!!table(dat[1:2])[,2])))
```

**c)** using `rowsum`

```
subset(dat, group %in% names(which((rowsum(key, group) > 0) [, 1])))
```

---

**3)** Using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%  
    group_by(group) %>%
    filter(sum(key) > 0)
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(group = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C"), key = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), value = c(3.97, 
2.05, 3.28, 4.22, 2.67, 5.02, 2.6, 3.99, 4.42)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```